# Как найти разницу во времени если значения времени это value словаря?

Tags: python

```
a = {'SVF2018-05-24': '12:02:58.917', 'NHR2018-05-24': '12:02:49.914', 'FAM2018-05-24': '12:13:04.512'}
b = {'SVF2018-05-24': '12:05:58.778 ', 'NHR2018-05-24': '12:06:27.441', 'SPF2018-05-24': '12:13:13.883'}
finish = {}
for i, x in a.items():
    for j, k in b.items():
        if i == j:
            key = j
            d1 = datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
            d2 = datetime.strptime(k, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
            val = str(d2 - d1)
            finish.update({key: val})
```

Делаю так, ругается

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FoxMinded\Task_6\report_1.py", line 23, in <module>
    d2 = datetime.strptime(k, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
  File "D:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "D:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

если вывожу отдельно d1 и d2 то:

```
1900-01-01 12:02:58.917000
1900-01-01 12:04:03.332000
1900-01-01 12:02:49.914000
1900-01-01 12:04:02.979000
1900-01-01 12:13:04.512000
1900-01-01 12:14:17.169000
1900-01-01 12:03:01.250000
1900-01-01 12:04:13.889000
1900-01-01 12:18:37.735000
1900-01-01 12:19:50.198000
1900-01-01 12:04:45.513000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\FoxMinded\Task_6\report_1.py", line 24, in <module>
    d2 = datetime.strptime(k, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
  File "D:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "D:\Python\lib\_strptime.py", line 352, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Comment: Укажите конкретную ошибку, которая у вас возникает. Полный текст ошибик со стектрейсом.

Comment: @insolor добавил

Comment: @NowhereMan нет, это точно не из за скобки, просто не скопировалась сюда

Comment: @НикитаБучацкий, это явно не полный текст ошибки. И где стектрейс ошибки? Стектрейс показывает, в каком конкретно месте у вас возникает ошибка.

Comment: @insolor так и понял)

Comment: После `ValueError: unconverted data remains:` еще что-то должно быть написано

Comment: только Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @insolor и в d1 нормально все заходит, значение попадает и выводиться, если отдельно вывести только d1, а вот d2 нет

Comment: Лишний пробел в конце строки `'12:05:58.778 '` во втором словаре. Нужно или поправить в самом словаре, или до конвертации применять метод strip к строкам с датами.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, все заработало